Load a custom post type template.html from a plugin
I'm using a Full Site Editing theme and have created a custom post type of 'walk', but I cant load a custom post type template.html from the plugin. I've put the single-walk.html in the '/templates' directory in the plugin and its not automatically found like it would be in a parent theme/child theme. So I tried registering it using PHP but it simply loads the HTML and not header and footer js/css etc. Is this not possible currently? I can move the file into the Child Theme and it works, but obviously not ideal. The PHP I tried is below:
function cpt_lv_wd_template_include($template) {
    if (is_singular('walk')) {
        // Check if a specific template exists in the plugin
        if (file_exists(CPT_LV_WD_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'templates/single-walk.html')) {
            return CPT_LV_WD_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'templates/single-walk.html';
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'cpt_lv_wd_template_include');


Your template should be single-walk.php.

what's the reason for doing this? This isn't how FSE is meant to work, would it not be better to register a pattern? Especially given you don't and can't know in advance how the header/etc are going to be set up, or what block hooks are present. Have you looked at the code/dev reference for get_block_template_part

So that I could set up a generic template design/layout for a custom post. If I created a 'Portfolio' CPT on one clients site in a plugin, I would like to quickly be able to replicate the Portfolio custom page layout on another clients website without having to manually create a new Custom Post Page layout it in the Site Editor, it would be more convenient to have a layout pre-made as a starter. I thought it would be easy and catered for already, it seems what I want is not the recommended way or possible currently? A pattern would still require a user/me to go into the site Editor.

None of the PHP functionality you're after will run because your files is .html.
From what I can tell your template inclusion filter is ok, there's some info missing like whether or not the CPT_LV_WD_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH constant is correct, but I'm operating under the assumption that it is because you said that the HTML is loading.
Functions like wp_head(), wp_header() and wp_footer() won't run in your template because it's an HTML file, so the server isn't trying to render the PHP in it.  I don't think the issue is how you include your template, I think the issue is the template itself.

Thanks and yes, the CPT_LV_WD_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH is correct. Really what I'm asking is what is the standard way to include a custom post type template file in a plugin when using a FSE/Block Editor Theme?

I have modified my file to be .php and look at the following resource: https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-use-php-templates-in-block-themes/ if I create a 'single-walk.php' file and use do_blocks I get what I was expecting to see: <?php
$block_content = '<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header"} /-->';

echo do_blocks($block_content);

?>

That's fantastic @Ross, glad it worked. :-)
